# How to open an image by clicking the image button

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to open another image when I press the image button - I am completely new to html. I heard that you need to use the onclick to get that. Here it is what I am trying:

```
input type="image" src="img/gallery/5.jpg" onclick="img/floor.jpg"
```

Where 5.jpg is the thumbnail view and floor.jpg is the target image (present in another directory).

But the above piece of code is not working for me.
What is the correct approach?

Why this is failing  ??
i used the solution to open a number of images

```
 <a href="img/5.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/5.jpg"/></a> 
            <a href="img/6.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/6.jpg"/></a>
            <a href="img/7.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/7.jpg"/></a>
            <a href="img/8.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/8.jpg"/></a>
            <a href="img/9.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/9.jpg"/></a>
            <a href="img/10.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/10.jpg"/></a>
```

but every time it opens only the 10.jpg
Help 
thanks

Comment: How do you want to display the 2nd image? In the same place as the first? Or maybe inside something like a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)?

Comment: Why not simply `<a href="img/floor.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/5.jpg" /></a>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use an input and javascript in the first place ?

Just use a link

```
<a href="img/floor.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/5.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: dude can u put the complete piece of code 
i mean starting from input type="image" to ...(the end)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @N.Nihar the html i provided should completely replace the `input` tag you have..

Comment: yeah bit silly ,I got that ,thanks for the help 
one more question what should i do to place the image in center,do i need to create a separate <div> or how ??

Comment: @N.Nihar center of what ? This solution just opens the image in the browser (*when viewing the image you are no longer on a page*). If you want to open the image in the same page as the link is, then you indeed need some javascript. but you will have to show use your page to help you..

Answer (score 0):

Just use a an onclick javascript event to toggle the visiblity of the second image.

something like below.

```
<input type="image" onclick="image.style.display=inline;">
<img src="../5.jpg" id="image" style="display:none;"
```